# Has the Orca infant mortality rate been 100% since the Fukushima disaster?

Tags: biology, environment, fukushima-daiichi

[This has been going around Facebook lately](http://humansarefree.com/2016/09/radiation-from-fukushima-now-causes-100.html). All accounts seem to stem from [this NaturalNews article](http://www.naturalnews.com/048440_killer_whales_Fukushima_radiation_extinction.html). I don't tend to see them as a reliable source of information, but I also haven't found any proof that contradicts their assertion.

> Balcomb also remarked:
>
> *We haven't had any survivals in babies for a couple of years. We have had stillborns and newborns die and a number of whales that appear to be pregnant but didn't ultimately produce any calves. It's like zero survival in birth rate here.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's easy to counter: the Seattle Times reports [nine live orca births just in Puget Sound in 2015](http://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/environment/puget-sound-orca-numbers-rise-fast-after-30-year-low-in-2014/).  The Times quotes NOAA and the Center for Whale Research as their source.  However, Natural News wasn't *entirely* wrong: the west coast whales [didn't have any live births in 2014 or 2013](http://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/ten-years-after-esa-listing-killer-whale-numbers-falling/).

Comment: ...and Bacomb was writing in January 2015.

Comment: The linked article that cites a lack of live births in the Southern Resident Killer Whales in 2013 and 2014 does not mention Fukushima as a cause. It instead attributes the decline to chemical pollutants, boats, and the decline of the salmon population due to fishing.

Comment: Thank you. That is useful. And David, yeah, whether people attribute a particular cause seems to have more to do with axes to grind than any actual attributability.